# why there is a bracket python

Tags: python, loops, one-liner

Why is the bracket present here in this code after b in if sum([x,y]) <=b "]" +[-1])

`return max([sum([x,y]) for x in keyboards for y in drives if sum([x,y]) <= b]+[-1])`
someone please explain the code

Comment: It is closing the square bracket opened just before `sum([x,y])`, which is part of the comprehension that you have formed.

Answer (score 0):

What you've got there is: `[list comprehension] + [-1]`. That creates a new list with the two lists combined.

For whatever reason, the author of that code wanted the max to at least be `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably switch to an editor that highlights matching braces and parentheses.

Your code rewritten, just by adding white space (which Python will ignore):

```
return max(
    [
        sum(
            [
                x,y
            ]
        ) 
        for x in keyboards 
        for y in drives 
        if sum(
            [
                x,y
            ]
        ) <= b
    ]
    +
    [
        -1
    ]
)
```

See how the brackets match?